# Version Blackberry10 MobileFirst Platform Application

Tags: blackberry-10, ibm-mobilefirst

I can give version on application-descriptor.xml :

```
    <iphone bundleId="com.Mordor.iphone" version="1.0.11.1">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </iphone>

   <android version="1.0.11.1">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey/>
            <packageName/>
        </security>
    </android>
    <blackberry10 version="1.0"/>
```

my android and iOS version is 1.0.11.1

I want to change my blackberry10 application with 1.0.0.1, but when i want to build and install. There is an error, because the version. 
Is there a way to change my blackberry10 applicaton version ??

This the error came from my Blackberry10 Webworks SDK :

```
 [INFO]    Target Classic-2c014a44 selected
[INFO]    Populating application source
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml
[INFO]    /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/lib/logger.js:28
[INFO]    TypeError: Object Error: Please enter a valid application version has no method 'replace'    at Object.module.exports.error (/Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/lib/logger.js:28:42)    at Object.module.exports.start (/Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/lib/packager.js:69:24)    at build (/Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/lib/build.js:123:39)    at /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:548:21    at /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:224:13    at iterate (/Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:131:13)    at /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:142:25    at /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:226:17    at /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:553:34    at /Users/robbywidyahartono/Documents/MobileFirstProject/Mordor/apps/Mordor/blackberry10/native/platforms/blackberry10/cordova/lib/build.js:105:64
[ERROR]   console.error("[ERROR]   " + msg.replace(//i, ""));                                         ^
An error has occurred
```

The config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="Mordor" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" rim:backButton="exit">
    <name>Mordor</name>
    <author email="application author's e-mail">application's author</author>
    <description>
       Mordor
    </description>
    <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
    </license>
    <access subdomains="true" origin="file:///store/home" />
    <access subdomains="true" origin="file:///SDCard" />

    <!-- start_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->
  <access subdomains="true" origin="https://example.com" />
  <!-- end_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->

    <access subdomains="true" origin="*" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-1024x600.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-600x1024.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-1280x768.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-768x1280.png" />
    <content src="webresources/skinLoader.html" />
    <rim:permissions>
        <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit>
    </rim:permissions>
 </widget>
```

Comment: Well what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0.

1. Create a project
2. Added an app and the BlackBerry10 environment
3. Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server

success

4. Changed the version id for the environment in application-descriptor.xml to 1.0.11.1
5. Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server

success

Comment: it is success, if just Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server. have you try to build and install it on the real device?? i used Blackberry10 Webworks SDK to build and install it

Comment: What version are you using when it fails?

Comment: MobileFirst version : 6.3
WebWorks SDK : 2.2.0.15

Comment: @RobbyWH, Can you provide the apps' config.xml file please?

Comment: @RobbyWH, we are not experiencing this. Is there anything else different that you're seeing/doing that will help us to reproduce this?